# Make counter based on response data after from Axios fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from a back-end using axios and want to make a counter based on how many tasks were completed. I get this information back from the data I am fetching. I am having trouble getting the count number to increment based on the response data from my back-end. I think I am ordering my code wrong or not understanding something with react hooks/life cycles. If you can take a loook at my code and point me in the right direction I will be extremely thankful!

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectToken } from "../../../redux/features/auth/tokenSlice";
import axios from "axios";


export default function ToDoList(props) {


  const token = useSelector(selectToken);
  const idToken = token.idToken;
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  console.log("count ----> ", count);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "https://backend.com/to-do-list",
      headers: {
        Authorization: idToken,
      },
    };

    //Fetch to do list completion status
    async function getToDoProgress() {
      try {
        const response = await axios(config);
        if (response.data.combinedObject.day_count > 1) {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }
        if (response.data.combinedObject.service_count > 1) {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }
        if (response.data.combinedObject.stripe_account) {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }
        setData(response.data.combinedObject);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    idToken && getToDoProgress();
  }, [idToken]);


  if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading</h1>;
  }

return <h1>you have completed {count} tasks!</h1>
```

Comment: useState is asynchronous and will group `set` calls to optimize renders, so all of your `setCounts` and `setData` calls are probably being lumped into a single render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates :

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
```

Edit: There's a youtube video on this topic here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0plTCQgsXs

Edit2: Possibly another way of doing this would be to do:

```
        const response = await axios(config);
        let countDiff = 0;
        if (response.data.combinedObject.day_count > 1) {
          countDiff++;
        }
        if (response.data.combinedObject.service_count > 1) {
          countDiff++;
        }
        if (response.data.combinedObject.stripe_account) {
          countDiff++;
        }
        setCount(count + countDiff);
        setData(response.data.combinedObject);
        setLoading(false);
```

Though for that setCount I would probably still use a functional update (but that could be because I don't know in enough detail how react works).